# cv2.rectangle() does not do anything

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I have a python script which looks like this:

```
import cv2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    predict_filename = "prediction.jpg"
    predict_cv2 = cv2.imread(prediction_filename)
    
    cv2.rectangle(predict_cv2, (50,50), (100,100), (225,0,225), 6)
    print("changing ", predict_filename , " done")
```

I am trying to draw boxes to display object detection results later on, but until now I am struggling to draw boxes onto pictures in general.
`prediction.jpg` exists in the same file as the script, but will stay the same when running the code. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use the cv2.imwrite statement to get the desired result, before the draw rectangle command.

```
cv2.imwrite("File_name.jpg", predict_cv2)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are drawing the rectangle on the numpy array of predict_cv2,if u want to save this image u need to use the command cv2.imwrite("file name", array to save)

```
import cv2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    predict_filename = "prediction.jpg"
    predict_cv2 = cv2.imread(prediction_filename)
    
    cv2.rectangle(predict_cv2, (50,50), (100,100), (225,0,225), 6)
    cv2.imwrite("ImageWithRectangle.jpg", predict_cv2)
    print("changing ", predict_filename , " done")
```

this should save the image with rectangle on the project folder.